# Trying to cancel $http request with {timeout: canceller.promise}

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I need some help debugging why the timeout property is getting passed as {} according to Chrome Dev Tools.

```
function request(options) {

    let canceller = this.$q.defer();

    if (this.canceller) {
        console.error('CANCELLING EARLIER REQUEST', this.canceller);
        this.canceller.resolve();
    }

    options.timeout = this.canceller.promise;

    console.warn('options =', options);
    console.warn('Submitting request : :: : ::);

    this.$http.post(url, options)
        .then( resp => {

            console.warn('Request complete!');
            this.canceller = null;
        });
}
```

I can't figure out how to create a testing environment, but here is how the console.logs would play out if you were to fire this function twice.

```
options Object {timeout: Promise}
Submitting request : :: : ::
CANCELLING EARLIER REQUEST Deferred {promise: Promise}   //second request fired
options Object {timeout: Promise} 
Submitting Request : :: : ::
Request Complete!                    //this is the first request
Request Complete!                    //this is the second request
```

---

Here is what I see in the network tab for each request:

```
Request payload:

{
    timeout: {}
}
```

Notice, the timeout is an empty object - is that why my second request does not cancel the first request? Is there an $httpProvider somewhere in my app that's scrubbing the param?

Comment: It isn't clear how this is supposed to be work. What's `params`? What's `formatter`? The whole thing just falls apart and misses the necessary detals. Please, provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @estus Thanks for your comment. I have simplified the example.

Comment: It is not obvious that `this` refers to the same object in both requests. `this.canceller` is not assigned to a deferred. A plunk that can replicate the issue would be helpful.